# Take inputs from two directories

Tags: python, loops

I try to run script that takes inputs from two different directories. I currently wrote this script. It is supposed to take 1 input from `vcf_directory`, 2nd input from `snp_directory`, run `count_cases.py` script and output it in different directory.

```
import os
import sys


vcf_directory = r'/home/vcf'
snp_directory = r'/home/dir'
case_py_file = r'count_cases.py'
out_directory = r'/home.out'

# change this line to correct the screening behaviour
args_sub_file = r'-v ###infilename### -s ###snpfilename### -o ###outdir######outfilename###'

 ##################USAGE: python count_cases.py -v test.vcf.gz -s snpfile.txt -o controlcounts.txt #################################

# intended to have arg passed with directory to screen
if sys.argv[1:]:
   startingpoint = sys.argv[1]

if not os.path.exists(out_directory):
    os.makedirs(out_directory)

for filename in os.listdir(vcf_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".vcf.gz"):
        tmp_file_cmd = case_py_file + ' ' + args_sub_file.replace('###infilename###', os.path.join(vcf_directory, filename)) + ' ' + args_sub_file.replace('###snpfilename###', os.path.join(snp_directory, filename))
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###outfilename###', filename.replace('.vcf.gz', '_casecount.txt')) 
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###outdir###', out_directory)

        print("running:","python2.7 " + tmp_file_cmd)
        os.system("python2.7 " + tmp_file_cmd)
```

I have background in shell scripting; there for example I could do something like this:

```
dir1 = /dir1
dir2 = /dir2
outdir = /outdir
for file in dir1 
do 
   file1 = $dir1/*.vcf.gz
   file2 = $dir2/*.txt
   out = $outdir/$file1".finished.txt"
   command --file1 --file2 --out
done
```

I tried to do something similar in Python (code above), but get error that second input is not found

```
count_cases.py: error: -s option requires an argument
```

Comment: Please print `tmp_file_cmd` before `os.system` command.

Comment: The error is in `count_cases.py`. Please provide a full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were trying to duplicate the argument for the file `count_cases.py` in a weird way. If you really want to duplicate just do two separate commands. For your code try something like:

```py
import os
import sys


vcf_directory = r'/home/vcf'
snp_directory = r'/home/dir'
case_py_file = r'count_cases.py'
out_directory = r'/home.out'


args_sub_file = r'-v ###infilename### -s ###snpfilename### -o ###outdir######outfilename###'

if not os.path.exists(out_directory):
    os.makedirs(out_directory)


for filename in os.listdir(vcf_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".vcf.gz"):
        tmp_file_cmd = case_py_file + ' ' + args_sub_file
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###infilename###', os.path.join(vcf_directory, filename))
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###snpfilename###', os.path.join(snp_directory, filename))
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###outfilename###', filename.replace('.vcf.gz', '_casecount.txt')) 
        tmp_file_cmd = tmp_file_cmd.replace('###outdir###', out_directory)

        print("running:","python2.7 " + tmp_file_cmd)
        os.system("python2.7 " + tmp_file_cmd)
```

And if you want to have argument on your script do something like that: (because your `if sys.argv[1:]:startingpoint = sys.argv[1];` doesn't seem to be used.)

```py
args = sys.argv[1::2]
values = sys.argv[2::2]
for arg, value in zip(args, values):
    if arg == '--snp':
        snp_directory = value
    elif arg == '--out':
        out_directory = value
```

Comment: Thank you!
However, I runned the given script